# Firefox remove all the unpinned blocks from quick launch

Tags: firefox

Firefox automatically populates quick launch icons with the sites I visit most often. I don't need it. How can I keep only sites I manually pinned there and keep all the other blocks empty?

Answer (score 1):

type "**about:config**" in address bar (without the quotation marks), press Enter.
Search for "**browser.taskbar.lists.frequent.enabled**", then change it to false by right-clicking it.

Comment: This parameter was missing in my Firefox, but I created it as a boolean and set to false. Is it correct?

Comment: Well, depends if it works or not. ;)
Which version of FF you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work - new item appeared